# Merging Visual Studio Windows Store App and Windows Phone App solutions

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, tfs

I have created a HTML5 (canvas+js) game 
for Windows 8.1  using Visual Studio Express 2013 
and for Windows Phone 8 using Visual Studio Express 2012 with Windows Phone SDK 8.

How can I merge those solutions into one, or create a new one correctly from beginning, so that the two projects would share most image, sound and javascript files. I would like to work with one set of files, since the files are mostly the same, and build for both platforms at the same time.

Is it possible? I am even willing to buy Visual Studio Pro 2013 to get this done.
Also can it be used in TFS then?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, you cannot merge them.

The easy route is to use share the files on both projects using the Add-as-a-Link technique (see [KB 306234](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234)).
For you sanity you should organize the shared files in their own folder, e.g.

```
\SolutionFolder
   \Shared
   \WinPhone
   \WinApp
```

Note that when you add a file, you must add it to both projects.